# Constraing WPF Canvas in ViewBox to Parent Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a tabular layout with one column. There is a canvas at the top, a spliter then a data grid. I want to constrain the canvas (in a Viewbox) to the upper grid area. How do I prevent the canvas from just rendering everywhere, but rather only in the "upper" grid?

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>    

                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"><Canvas x:Name="canvas" /></Viewvox>


                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="5" ResizeDirection="Rows" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" />    
</Grid>
```

Comment: Set proper Row and Column ! What else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Canvases` must always be used with width/height. You want your `ViewBox` to scale the canvas, but it has no idea how big the canvas is.
2. Your canvas should also set `ClipToBounds` to `true`.
3. If you have no idea how big the Canvas should be, because the contents can be placed anywhere, then you should consider using other panels. All `Shape` classes can be placed onto any Panel.